# Looking for a textbook on electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for a **free** physics textbook on electromagnetism that wouldn't throw at me things to remember rather I'd love to have something which builds notions block by block, deriving coulomb's law instead of just presenting it as is for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Classical Theory of Fields
by L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz

https://archive.org/details/TheClassicalTheoryOfFields/page/n65

this is worth studying in detail.